# How do I Automatically Request Facebook APP connect on links to website from FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I apologize in advance, I have searched for 30 and cannot find.

There used to be a way that if anyone linked to your website via FB, Facebook requested Connect / Auth for your App before actually sending the traffic out to your website.

Did they pull this feature? Or an I missing a radio button?

(Ps, I know I can request on page load; however, I would prefer to use Facebooks method unless this has been removed.)

Comment: That was called “authenticated referrals”, and has been removed quite a while ago – see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cbroe's answer about authenticated referrals being depreciated is correct. There is no longer a way of doing this without triggering a rerral request

onLoad, etc.